Can i upload my Nextjs 14 application into a siteground? without cPanel?
I just created my website but I am not able to upload to siteground, because I inserted next-intl and from what I noticed next-intl does not support next export.
I'm trying to upload my single page application in Nextjs to siteground

You better ask your hosting provider whether they support this technologies or not. But, they should be support this feature.
